# How to change items in ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a main activity that includes a `ListView` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_grid"

        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"

        android:columnCount="4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="MainTitle"
            android:textSize="32dip"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

which uses the following adapter (`ListAdapter.java`):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values[position];

        System.out.println(s);

        if (s.equals("WindowsMobile")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon4);
        } else if (s.equals("iOS")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
        } else if (s.equals("Blackberry")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon3);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon4);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

to simply show an icon and some text. However, the four entries shown are very small in contradiction to examples I have found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) and [here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) and [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-tutorial-and-basic-example.html)! I have changed the attributes `layout_height` (wrap_content, fill_parent, ...), `layout_width`, `minHeight` and `textSize`, but none of it seems to change the overall size of each of the `ListView` entries. They stay very small, and also do not correspond to the preview shown in `AndroidStudio`.

How can I change the size of the items in the `ListView`?

Comment: Hey @Alex, please post the contents of the **list_layout** XML file.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. The settings are defined in the OTHER layout! I forgot. I guess this is the solution already. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In list_layout.xml file you can increment textSize for TextView.

Answer (score 0):

In the method getView, you inflate the layout where you define each item. There you should change the properties of the items. 
Also you should inflate this layout just for the first item. Your code should be

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null || !convertView.getTag().equals(TAG_NULL)) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layou, parent, false);
    }
```

and the `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` in the constructor